# python read two different files with for

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io

mates.

I'm starting using python these days while I used to try things with java, although more complicated.

When I try to read two different files like:

```
a = open("file1.txt")
b = open("file2.txt")
for abc in a
    for def in b
        print (abc,def)
```

However what I get is just the first line of file a together with each line of file b. It's different from what I expect.

What's the reason for that and is there anyway to solve it?
Cheers.

Comment: This code can't run, `.txt` is not a string, further, do you have a filename ".txt" ?

Comment: Do you get the first line of file a with all lines of file b followed by the second line of file a with all lines of file b, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use`zip()`:

```
for (line_a, line_b) in zip(a, b):
   ...
```

This will take the first line of `a` and the first line of `b`, then the second line of both files etc. It will stop when the shorter of the two files ends.

Comment: @t.m.adam: Right, thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop reads all the lines from `b` meaning that the file is exhausted (all the lines have already been read). In order to read the lines again you need to move back to the start of the file with `b.seek(0)`.

Alternatively, before looping over it, you could convert `b` into a list with `b = list(b)`. The list can be looped over multiple times without having to go back to the start.

Comment: Thanks, mate. It works! I have thought it might be similar to the for look in java. However, I don't know the mechanism of exhausting file in python.